# Move child to the left (outside) of parent

Tags: css

I want a child of a `div` to be positioned to the left of its parent as if they were both sibling `spans`. That is, the child is actually completely outside of the parent.

The *size of the child varies*, but the parent has a fixed size.

[image: Desired result]

I have tried using a combination of `position: absolute` with a negative margin, like so:

```
.parent {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: -100%;
}
```

But that didn't work. I also tried many combinations of margins and positions, such as `right: -100%`, `right: 0; margin-left: 100%` and nothing works.

I tried using the same combination of `right: 0` with a negative `margin-right`, instead using pixel values. While it does work, it's not ideal. I have multiple of those in my page (they are generated by code) and the size of the child always varies. Is there a CSS-only solution?

Comment: where is HTML ?

Comment: @NishargShah oh, I didn't think it was needed since the structure (one div inside another) was simple enough. I should remove that tag, thanks

Comment: i posted answer, look out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply add `left: 100%` in your child element.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: teal;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, of course I didn't think of that. I was over complicating everything. Thanks, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Genial! :) And `right: 100%` if you need to position it before the parent...